# MSYS2 error collect2: fatal error cannot find ld

Tags: c, mingw, mingw32, msys2, mingw-w64

Whenever I try to compile my program using GCC on `msys2` I get this error:

> `collect2: fatal error cannot find 'ld'`

This is what I am writing to compile:

```
gcc 'pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0' -o example.exe example.c 'pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: @xing Still doesn't work

Comment: What's the output of `which gcc`?  What compiler toolchain packages did you install with pacman?

Comment: @DavidGrayson I installed x64_mingw-w64-gcc or something like that and then it said that i didn't have the command gcc or what i installed first so i tried pacman -S gcc and it installed and can compile but doesn't have ld

Comment: Sounds like you want to compile 64-bit native Windows programs so you should run the MinGW-w64 64-bit shell and install mingw-w64-86_64-toolchain and make sure that `which gcc` is /mingw64/bin/gcc

Comment: @DavidGrayson I tried pacman -S mingw-w64_86_64-toolchain but it didn't work. How would I install it?

Comment: Oops, try: pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain